# How to replace different occurances in SQL?

Tags: sql

**I have the following query:**

```
Select PERSON_NAME, Mobile_Nr, replace(Message, 'text 8' ,'yes') as SMSs from PERSON a
    inner join USER_MOBILE b on a.ID_PERSON=b.ID_USER
    inner join MOBILE_NUMBER c on b.ID_MOBILE=C.ID
    inner join MESSAGE_ID d on c.ID=d.ID_Mobile
    where a.Person_Name not in 
    (Select PERSON_NAME from PERSON a
    inner join USER_MOBILE b on a.ID_PERSON=b.ID_USER
    inner join MOBILE_NUMBER c on b.ID_MOBILE=C.ID
    inner join CALL_ID d on c.ID=d.ID_Mobile)
```

**It returns:**

```
      PERSON_NAME           Mobile_Nr   SMSs
First name 5 Last name 5    797900012   yes
First name 5 Last name 5    797900012   text 9
First name 5 Last name 5    797900016   text 13
```

**How can I change all the values in SMSs to Yes in my query?**

Comment: What table is the 'Message' column in?

Comment: When should the query return a value other than 'yes'?

Comment: No conditions, it is just a requirement. It has to be in the select query.

Comment: No what I am asking is when do you want to not return 'yes'. When would you return 'no'?

Comment: If you always want yes, use Michael's answer

Comment: There is no requirement or condition to return No. What I am asked to do is to change all the values of SMSs to yes for the results of this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood right. Is that what you want?

```
Select PERSON_NAME, Mobile_Nr, SMSs = 'Yes' from PERSON a
inner join USER_MOBILE b on a.ID_PERSON=b.ID_USER
inner join MOBILE_NUMBER c on b.ID_MOBILE=C.ID
inner join MESSAGE_ID d on c.ID=d.ID_Mobile
where a.Person_Name not in 
(Select PERSON_NAME from PERSON a
inner join USER_MOBILE b on a.ID_PERSON=b.ID_USER
inner join MOBILE_NUMBER c on b.ID_MOBILE=C.ID
inner join CALL_ID d on c.ID=d.ID_Mobile)
```

Comment: Yes, that works, I was just thinking too much on the REPLACE() function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do (assuming the 'Message' column is in the 'MESSAGE_ID' table)?

```
UPDATE MESSAGE_ID SET Message='Yes'
FROM PERSON a
inner join USER_MOBILE b on a.ID_PERSON=b.ID_USER
inner join MOBILE_NUMBER c on b.ID_MOBILE=C.ID
inner join MESSAGE_ID d on c.ID=d.ID_Mobile
where a.Person_Name not in 
(Select PERSON_NAME from PERSON a
inner join USER_MOBILE b on a.ID_PERSON=b.ID_USER
inner join MOBILE_NUMBER c on b.ID_MOBILE=C.ID
inner join CALL_ID d on c.ID=d.ID_Mobile)
```

Comment: The idea is correct but I want to keep the select. So I make the replace inside the select query.